# MediaWiki - How to handle slash and backslash in title

Tags: mediawiki

I would like to use article names which contains "/" (slash) and/or "\" (backslash).

example:

- http://www.example.com/wiki/**Media/Wiki**
- http://www.example.com/wiki/**Media\Wiki**

how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do so, you can [enable subpages](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Subpages) in any MediaWiki namespace editing [`$wgNamespacesWithSubpages`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgNamespacesWithSubpages) in `LocalSettings.php`. For example:

```
# Enable subpages in the main namespace
$wgNamespacesWithSubpages[NS_MAIN] = true;
```

If you do this, `Media/Wiki` will be a subpage of "Media" and it will show a link to the parent page under the page title (like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Citation/doc)):

[image: Link to the parent page in MediaWiki]

By default, MediaWiki enables subpages for all namespaces except main (ns0).

About page titles, the MediaWiki [manual](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Subpages) says:

> It's not possible to use forward slashes in the title of a page from a
>   namespace where subpages are activated, however back slashes (`\`) are
>   treated as normal characters in subpage naming and can be used in
>   place of forward slashes.

See also the documentation for the variable [`$wgLegalTitleChars`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgLegalTitleChars).

Comment: I think that if you want to use slash as normal part of page name, you should *not* enable subpages. Because the page with a slash shouldn't be logically a subpage and slashes in names are allowed even without that.

Comment: Yes, if you don't enable subpages the slash will be part of the page title. I was just unsure about what the wanted behaviour was. :)